# operator<< overload in C++ for a class in class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

i have the following classes:

```
class mypipe {
    class node {
        public:
            char ch;
            node* next;

            node(){...}
            node(char c){..}
    } ;      
public:
    unsigned int size;
    node* head;
```

and i need to overload the operator<<, to print the mypipe as it is now.

then,  i'm trying to write the following:

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& stream, mypipe p)  {
     node* curr = p.head -> next;
...
```

immediately after the variables definition.
the problem is that i get an error  "identifier node is undefined".
i've tried to declare the operator and implement it outside of the class, that didn't help.

does anyone have any ideas about it?
thanks in advance for anyone who can help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`node` is an inner class, which means you have to qualify its type:

```
mypipe::node* curr = p.head -> next;
```

Comment: Only because it is a nonmember function. And no need to assume node is public. The operator is a friend

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan True, I removed the part related to your second point. Thanks, I missed that :)